# Laravel how to match 2 values with one field

Tags: mysql, laravel

Currently I am facing problem that I am using `orWhere` to get the correct result but not getting the exact result. I want to get result where my field contain only **Paid** and **Flexible**

E.g
**Status**

- Paid
- Paid
- Flexible
- Paid
- Paid
- Flexible

But with this query I am also getting **UnPaid** but I don't want **UnPaid** result

```
$orders = Order::with('orderfiles','orderStatus','orderDelivery','flexibleDelivery')->whereHas('payment', function ($query) {
            $query->where("status","=",'Paid')->orwhere('status' ,'=', 'Flexible');
      })->whereBetween("tbl_orders.order_date",  $range)->where('domain_id','=',$domain_id)->orderBy('order_date','asc')->paginate();
           return View('admin.all_orders')
               ->with('orders',$orders)->with('title','Results - Paid and Flexible Orders')->with('logoNum',$domain_id);
```

**Sql**

```
Array
(
    [0] => select count(*) as aggregate from `tbl_orders` where (select count(*) from `tbl_payments` where `tbl_payments`.`order_id` = `tbl_orders`.`order_id` and `status` = ? or `status` = ?) >= 1 and `tbl_orders`.`order_date` between ? and ? and `domain_id` = ?
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paid
            [1] => Flexible
            [2] => 2015-01-01
            [3] => 2015-05-31
            [4] => 18
        )

    [2] => 7233.41
    [3] => mysql
)
```

Comment: Try printing out your SQL with `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`  before the return (if you're using Laravel 5, you will probably need to enable the query log) and post this too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Db::RAW 
for more help read: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

```
$orders = Order::with('orderfiles','orderStatus','orderDelivery','flexibleDelivery')->whereHas('payment', function ($query) {
        $query->where(DB::raw('(`status` = \'Paid\') OR (`status` = \'Flexible\')'));
      })->whereBetween("tbl_orders.order_date",  $range)->where('domain_id','=',$domain_id)->orderBy('order_date','asc')->paginate();
           return View('admin.all_orders')
               ->with('orders',$orders)->with('title','Results - Paid and Flexible Orders')->with('logoNum',$domain_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you’ve already accepted an answer, but it’s really not the best way. You could use Laravel’s `whereIn` query method:

```
$query->whereIn('status', ['Paid', 'Flexible']);
```

The first parameter is the column name, and the second is an array of values you want to match.